# AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute '__version__'

Tags: python, pandas

**Please note, this is not a duplicate question. I'm aware of how to find versions of libraries in python. What's caught my goat is the apparent anomaly when the __version__ command is called in two different ways.**

Has anyone faced this before? When I type the following in IDLE, I get the output which specifies the pandas version.

```
>>>import pandas as pd
>>>print(pd.__version__)
0.22.0
```

When I put the same two lines of code into a program, save it and run it, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute '__version__'
```

It does not make any sense to me. Appreciate any thoughts on this please.

Comment: Try `pd.__version__`.

Comment: Don't name your file `pandas.py`

Comment: Hi Burhan, The file isn't named pandas.py. I've given it some random file name.

Comment: jpp - I get the same error when i run it without the print command like you mentioned.

Comment: using `pd.__version__`  worked in version `0.25.1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're not importing the real `pandas` module when you run your script from a file. When I run your script in a file on my machine it prints the pandas version correctly.

Maybe you have a file called `pandas.py` or a directory called `pandas` in your current working directory when you run the script? Or maybe there is a `pandas.py` or a `pandas` directory in a directory in your PYTHONPATH environment variable? (Other than the real pandas, that is.) Try running this program and see if the output looks like the proper pandas source file, or something else.

```
import pandas as pd
print(pd.__file__)
```

Comment: In my case: `pd.__file__` is located at `anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py` and yet I have this error

Comment: @wander95 I recommend posting a new question with the details of your situation; what version of Pandas you have, what version of Anaconda you have, what Python script you are trying to run, and the method or command you use to invoke that script.